# Find out counts for every minute in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a machine which inserts a forever-going-up counter into a table whenever the counter changes. And I need to find the total for each minute by extracting the last row in each minute and subtract from last minute's. The table looks like this. The date_time column doesn't exist. I include it for human to read.

[Image for the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAlur.png)

So I am expecting the query result like this:

```
2  2021-07-23 15:50
0  2021-07-23 15:49
15 2021-07-23 15:48
```

I tried to use `Partition` and `Row_Number` but got overflow.

Comment: Sample data as an image is helpful to no one - include the actual sample data and desired results as text in your question, ideally with create and insert statwmwnts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the date_time at minute-level precision and grouping on that. Then you just count the rows in each group.

```
SELECT FORMAT(date_time, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm') as Time_Minute, COUNT(*) as TicksInMinute
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY FORMAT(date_time, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: FYI - FORMAT is incredibly slow and really isn't needed here.  If you want to round to the nearest minute you can cast the value to smalldatetime (rounds up for greater than 30 seconds - rounds down less than 30 seconds).  If you want to truncate to the nearest minute: dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, getdate()), 0).  Either of these will perform an order of magnitude faster than using format.